Unable to fill date combobox in playwright using typescript
I'm unable to fill this date comobobox with a value. fill() is not working. An tried like below. But it works sometimes but other times it only selects a portion of the value (dag.måned.år) and repalce it.
await this.courseStartDate.focus()
await this.page.keyboard.press('Control+A')
await this.page.keyboard.type('17.09.2026')

This is how html code looks like.


Please share the page and a [mcve].

Unrelated, but why do you have undefined and false in your CSS classes?

Just use fill, do Not type via the keybaord.
await this.page.locator('#courseStartDate').fill('17/09/2026')

In order to clean the input field use Clear:
await this.page.locator('#courseStartDate').clear()

